# Is there any way to introspect image values while building a container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For instance, let's say we have this

```
LABEL interpreter_version="3.3.3"
```

We might need to get that value from inside the Dockerfile while we build it, for instance something like this

```
ENV PATH="/path/to/version-manager/versions/$interpreter_version/bin:$PATH"
```

However, `LABEL` values are only available from `docker inspect`, which is obviously not reachable from the build process. There's [this proposal for container introspection](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8427), which has not been accepted, but no other way. Is there any workaround to achieve that kind of thing?

Comment: At least for `$PATH`, you can use a fixed path, even something like `/usr/local/bin` that's on `$PATH` by default.  Since a Docker image provides strong filesystem isolation you don't need a version manager or to qualify paths by a specific installed version, also since you'll presumably only have one version in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to consume from `ARG` instead of LABEL, as ARG considered is [build time variable](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/), you can also overide ARG at build time, where `LABLE`  are designed for [meta data](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/).

Also, there are some guideline for using Label.

> Label keys should begin and end with a lower-case letter and should
>   only contain lower-case alphanumeric characters, the period character
>   (.), and the hyphen character (-). Consecutive periods or hyphens are
>   not allowed.

[docker-label-guide-line](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/)

So the option is Docker **build time ARG**.

```
ARG interpreter_version="3.3.3"
ENV PATH="/path/to/version-manager/versions/$interpreter_version/bin:$PATH"
```